# Programming error with string index out of range python

Tags: python

Every time I try to run my code and open a specific text document which is fairly long, it says string index out of range. I was wondering if any of you could help me solve this problem. I have to get my code to spit out more than what I have it doing right now, but this is a start and I didn't figure it wise to carry on without fixing the initial error.

```
file = open(input("Enter File Name:"))
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
number_chars = 0
number_words = 0
largest_word = ""
smallest_word = ""
count_words = 0
largest = int(0)
smallest = int(999999)
average = 0
count = 0
sum = 0
for item in lines:
    is_word = False
    item = item.strip()
    char = item[0]
    count_words = count_words + 1
    if char >= 'a' and char <= 'z':
        is_word = True
    elif char >= 'A' and char <= 'Z':
        is_word = True
    if is_word == True:
        if(len(largest_word) < len(item)):
            largest_word = item
        if(len(smallest_word) > len(item)):
            smallest_word = item
        number_chars += len(item)
    else:
        item = int(item)
        count = count + 1
        sum = sum + item
        if(count == 1 or item > largest):
            largest = item
        if(count == 1 or item < smallest):
            smallest = item
print("Reading", "name_list.txt")
print("found",count,"numbers")
print("largest number :", largest)
print("smallest numer :", smallest)
Average = sum // count
print("Average :", Average)

print(largest_word)
print(smallest_word)
```

Answer (score 2):

The *first* thing I'd be thinking about is the effect an empty line is going to have on the statements (primarily the last one):

```
file = open(input("Enter File Name:"))
lines = file.readlines()
for item in lines:
    item = item.strip()
    char = item[0]
```

An empty line will not *have* an index zero.

In terms of *fixing* it, it depends on your intent. From a casual glance, it appears that you treat each line as either a word or a number (though you may want to consider what happens if the line starts with `:`, for example - that won't be considered a word by your code and it's almost certainly going to cause problems when treating it as an integer).

However, putting that aside for now: since a blank line is neither a word *nor* a number, you may find the simplest fix is to simply ignore those blank lines totally, with something like:

```
item = item.strip()   # This line already exists.
if item == "":
    continue
```

A blank `item` will simply cycle around and get the next line.

However, as mentioned, this will only fix your *immediate* problem, you really should consider handling things that are not in the set `{word, number}`.

Comment: So I need to remove the char = item[0]?

Comment: @Shane, see the update, easiest solution for that particular case is probably just to ignore blank lines totally.